# Finding the vector norm

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How would I solve the following problem.

Find the value of $a$ such that $z=2i-j+ak$ is three times as long as $b=2i+j-k$

would this mean that the value of a=3 so that k is three times as long in a than in b.

Comment: It might be a good idea not to name your vector and your variable the same letter.

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's being asked is this:

$$\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + a^2} = 3\sqrt{2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2}.$$

Squaring both sides gives

$$5 + a^2 = 54.$$

So $a = \pm 7.$

Comment: yes this makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

$|a|=\sqrt{2^2+(-1)^2+a^2}=3\times |b|=3\times \sqrt{2^2+1^2+(-1)^2}$

Answer (score 1):

Length of your vector $\mathbb{a}=(2^2+1^2+a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Length of $\mathbb{b}=6^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

You are given:
$(2^2+1^2+a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=3\cdot6^{\frac{1}{2}}$. Can you find the value of $a$ now?